# If phantomjs render is blocking, why doesn't this work

Tags: phantomjs

So I have a for loop that goes through an array of urls, submits them to wave.webaim.org and makes a render of the page. Simple. However if after the loop I put an exit my images never render

```
   for(x = 0; x < crawlarray.length; x++) {
        uri = crawlarray[x];
        encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri);
        var webaim = "http://wave.webaim.org/report#/" + uri;
        webpage.open(webaim, function(status) {
            webpage.render(encoded + '.png');

        });
    }

    phantom.exit(0);
```

If I remove the phantom.exit my images render.

How do I get these images to render and then exit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized now that while render is blocking, open is not, since the render is inside open then I get the problem that render never gets run because the loop is finished before the webpage.open has a chance to finish.